# Calculate price in model, each time accessing model in laravel without saving in database

Tags: laravel, eloquent, model

I need to calculate price after discount each time I access my model Product. There are fields to store price and discount but no final price after discount. How can I do that in the model so that every time I access the records from the model discounted price is calculated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add [mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-mutators) in your Product Model, it will become a virtual attribute, something like this:

```php
    public function getPriceAttribute($value)
    {
        return $value - $this->discount * $value; // Here just the example, add your logic to calculate the price.
    }
```

So you can access the price after discount in each product.

```php
Product::first()->price
```

If you don't want the discounted price to overwrite your original price, you can change to another attribute name like `discounted_price`:

```php
    protected $appends = ['discounted_price'];

    public function getDiscountedPriceAttribute()
    {
        return $this->price - $this->discount * $this->price; // Here just the example, add your logic to calculate the price.
    }
```

Access the discounted_price:

```php
Product::first()->discounted_price
```

Comment: How do I access it from controller?

Comment: @NisthaAdhikari something like this: `Product::find($id)->price`. Access it like a normal attribute.

Comment: if you don't want the discounted price to overwrite your original price, you can change to another attribute name

Comment: Can this not be used for collection instead of a single record?

Comment: @NisthaAdhikari you can do something like this: `Product::tack(5)->get()->pluck('discounted_price')`, and you can check `Product::all()->toArray()` in tinker.

Comment: Thank you, This helped. I appreciate your time.